# How to center a checkbox in a table cell?

Tags: html, css

The cell contains nothing but a checkbox. It is rather wide because of text in the table header row. How do I center the checkbox (with inline CSS in my HTML? (I know))

I tried

```
 <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="myTextEditBox" value="checked" 
      style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
 </td>
```

but that didn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

---

Update: here's a test page. Can someone please correct it - with CSS inline in the HTML - so that the checkboxes are centered in their columns?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Alignment test</title>
</head>
<body>

<table style="empty-cells:hide; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" border="1"   cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">

  <tr>
    <th>Search?</th><th>Field</th><th colspan="2">Search criteria</th><th>Include in report?<br></th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="query_myTextEditBox" style="text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;">    
    </td>

    <td>
      myTextEditBox
    </td>

    <td>
       <select size ="1" name="myTextEditBox_compare_operator">
        <option value="=">equals</option>
        <option value="<>">does not equal</option>
       </select>
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" name="myTextEditBox_compare_value">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="report_myTextEditBox" value="checked" style="text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;">
    </td>

  </tr>

</table>


</body>
</html>
```

---

I have accepted @Hristo's answer - and here it is with inline formatting ...

```
<table style="empty-cells:hide;" border="1"   cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">

    <tr>
        <th>Search?</th><th>Field</th><th colspan="2">Search criteria</th><th>Include in report?<br></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="query_myTextEditBox">    
        </td>

        <td>
            myTextEditBox
        </td>

        <td>
            <select size ="1" name="myTextEditBox_compare_operator">
                <option value="=">equals</option>
                <option value="<>">does not equal</option>
            </select>
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="text" name="myTextEditBox_compare_value">
        </td>

        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="report_myTextEditBox" value="checked">
        </td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: <td align="center"> <input type="checkbox" name="myTextEditBox" value="checked" ></td> will make it work in IE8,9. However in IE10 or chrome, the checkbox or radiobox is defined in a box, no matter you see the box or not. The box will always left aligned. But inside the defining box, the checkbox or radio is centered. If the width of the containing TD is 100px, the checkbox is 50px, then it is always left aligned. To center the checkbox, you can make the defining box of the chekbox to be 100px, which is the the same width of the containing TD.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

How about this... http://jsfiddle.net/gSaPb/

---

Check out my example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QzPGu. Code snippet:

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  /* center checkbox horizontally */
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* center checkbox vertically */
}

table {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
}

tr {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="myTextEditBox" value="checked" /> checkbox
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work in my example. Please see updated question

Comment: +1 That works. I have posted the updated code - with inline formatting - above. Now I just have to do some file compare & figure out the difference that makes it work., Thanks

Comment: Close, but seems slightly off with my bootstrap-4 table. The column header is definitely centered, but the checkbox is a bit left of center

Answer (score 33):

Try

```
<td style="text-align:center;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="myTextEditBox" value="checked" />
</td>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work in my example. Please see updated question

Comment: I just tested your updated code using my solution in Chrome 9 and it works.

Comment: +1 If it works in MS IE and FireFox and you post the code here, then the answer is yours.

Answer (score 24):

Try this, this should work,

```
td input[type="checkbox"] {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

This should work, I am using it:

```
<td align="center"> <input type="checkbox" name="myTextEditBox" value="checked" ></td>
```

Comment: @Gerard, who is talking here about the HTML5 ?

Answer (score 5):

For dynamic writing td elements and not rely directly on the td Style

```
  <td>
     <div style="text-align: center;">
         <input  type="checkbox">
     </div>
  </td>
```

Comment: Maybe rather <span> than <div> ?

Comment: div is a block-element; its default display value is “block”. With span, input continues on left. Test to see difference

Comment: A good explanation, which will help others in future (+1) Welcome aboard

Answer (score 4):

**Pull out ALL of your in-line CSS**, and move it to the head. Then **use classes** on the cells so you can adjust everything as you like (don't use a name like "center" - you may change it to left 6 months from now...). The alignment answer is still the same - apply it to the `<td>` NOT the checkbox (that would just center your check :-) )

Using you code...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Alignment test</title>
<style>
table { margin:10px auto; border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid gray; }
td,th { border:1px solid gray; text-align:left; padding:20px; }
td.opt1 { text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; }
td.opt2 { text-align:right; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>

      <tr>
        <th>Search?</th><th>Field</th><th colspan="2">Search criteria</th><th>Include in report?<br></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="opt1"><input type="checkbox" name="query_myTextEditBox"></td>
        <td>
          myTextEditBox
        </td>
        <td>
           <select size ="1" name="myTextEditBox_compare_operator">
            <option value="=">equals</option>
            <option value="<>">does not equal</option>
           </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="myTextEditBox_compare_value"></td>
        <td class="opt2">
          <input type="checkbox" name="report_myTextEditBox" value="checked">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Don't forget...a `td` is a "special" kind of element. It has it's own unique behaviors - like a block and in-line marriage (from hell).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't support legacy browsers, I'd use [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) because it's [well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) and will simply solve most of your layout problems.

```
#table-id td:nth-child(1) { 
    /* nth-child(1) is the first column, change to fit your needs */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

This centers all content in the first `<td>` of every row.

Answer (score 1):

Define the float property of the check element to none:

```
float: none;
```

And center the parent element:

```
text-align: center;
```

It was the only that works for me.

Comment: An inherited "float: left;" was ruining it for me. Setting "float: none" fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th class="text-center">Left</th>
      <th class="text-center">Center</th>
      <th class="text-center">Right</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <span>Bootstrap (class="text-left")</span>
      </th>
      <td class="text-left">
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" checked />
      </td>
      <td class="text-right">
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <span>HTML attribute (align="left")</span>
      </th>
      <td align="left">
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" checked />
      </td>
      <td align="right">
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that there was a parent style with `position: absolute !important` which I was not allowed to edit.

So I gave my specific checkbox `position: relative !important` and it fixed the vertical misalignment issue.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that your `<td>` is not `display: block;`

Floating will do this, but much easier to just: `display: inline;`