# how to center a checkbox with text in a table cell?

Tags: html, html-table

I am facing problem to align the checkbox in the table cell

```
<table style="empty-cells:hide;" border="1"   cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">

<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        test 1 - 
        <input type="checkbox" name="query_myTextEditBox">    
        test 2 - 
        myTextEditBox
        <select size ="3" name="myTextEditBox_compare_operator">
            <option value="1">option 1</option>
            <option value="2">option 2</option>
        </select>
    </td>

    <td valign="top">
        <input type="text" value="my text" name="myTextEditBox">
    </td>

</tr>
```

[my test on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/dsea/QCr3a/1/)

for some specific reason, I don't want to separate text & checkbox into 2 cells

I did see this post [How to center a checkbox in a table cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048485/how-to-center-a-checkbox-in-a-table-cell) but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: are you want like this http://jsfiddle.net/gSaPb/ or how?

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="vertical-align:top"` to the `<select>` element.

Comment: it works almost. see here http://jsfiddle.net/dsea/QCr3a/4/. i wonder if the 1st could be aligned like the 2nd one? thanks

Comment: I said to add it to the `<select>`, not the `<input>` ;)