# How to align textbox to left in Struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

[image: How to align Menu order textbox to left]

Hi How to align Menu order textbox to left. Please help...

```
<tr>
                <s:hidden    id="id"        name="userMenuEntity.userMenuId"/>
                <s:textfield id="name"      name="userMenuEntity.userMenuName"  key="label.menuName" maxlength="15" size="30" required="true" labelSeparator=""/>
                <s:textfield id="link"      name="userMenuEntity.userMenuLink"  key="label.menuLink" maxlength="20" size="30" required="true" labelSeparator=""/>
                <s:textfield id="order"     name="userMenuEntity.userMenuOrder" key="label.menuOrder" maxlength="3" size="10" required="true" labelSeparator=""/>
                <s:select    id="parentId"  name="userMenuEntity.userParentMenuId"  key="label.menuNameSelect" list="parentMenuList" headerKey="0" headerValue="-- Select Meny Type --" cssStyle="width:205px;" required="true" labelSeparator=""/>
                <s:radio     id="status"    name="commonFields.userActive"      key="label.status" list="userMenuStatus" required="true" labelSeparator=""/>
                <s:textfield id="cdate"     name="commonFields.userCreatedDate" key="label.CreatedDt" size="30" readonly="true" cssStyle="background-color:#E7EBDD;" required="true" labelSeparator=""/>
                <s:textfield id="mdate"     name="commonFields.userModifiedDate" key="label.ModifiedDt" size="30" readonly="true" cssStyle="background-color:#E7EBDD;" required="true" labelSeparator=""/>
            </tr>
```

My Jsp is above

Below is the generated HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class="tdLabel"><label for="order" class="label">Menu Order<span class="required">*</span></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="userMenuEntity.userMenuOrder" size="10" maxlength="3" value="" id="order"/></td>
</tr>
```

Kindly check. I am not able to figure it out the malformed HTML... Thankx!!!

Comment: Thankx for ur response, but Jsp is not getting posted....

Comment: Post the relevant code not JSP as a file.

Comment: Look at generated HTML it is malformed. Fix this first.

Comment: If you are using default `xhtml` theme and putting `<s:textfield>` into `tr` then it will be malformed, because `xhtml` adds `tr` around elements and `tr` is not allowed directly inside another `tr`.

Comment: Okay. I removed tr, then How to Align Menu Order Textbox to left?

Comment: By default textbox alignment is at center, how to adjust it to left. Is there any best css to do that instead of xhtml??

Comment: You can try with `text-align` css property.

Comment: Dear  Aleksandr M, I think U r getting me wrong... I m not talking about the alignment of text inside the textbox, I m talking abt the alignment of textbox itself...

Comment: Don't be confused with property name. :) See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5048485/1700321.

Comment: ...then change background-color, color and border-color to gain tolerability :>

Comment: after all changes switch to the simple theme ;)

Comment: Can U all provide me full example for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `<head>` tag apply

```
<style>
#tableName td {
text-align: left;
}
</style>
```